# Getting problem in opening oracle sqldeveloper in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, oracle-sqldeveloper

When I'm running ./sqldeveloper.sh in the terminal after entering into sqldeveloper folder, I'm getting this exception:

```
disha@dn:~/IDE/sqldeveloper$ ./sqldeveloper.sh

Oracle SQL Developer
Copyright (c) 2005, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /usr/lib/jvm/java-18-openjdk-amd64/lib/libawt_xawt.so
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2398)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:785)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1979)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:395)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:234)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:176)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.findFromPaths(NativeLibraries.java:322)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:289)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2403)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:848)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:2015)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:1392)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:1390)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1389)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.initStatic(Toolkit.java:1427)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1401)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.<clinit>(Component.java:625)
    at oracle.ide.osgi.boot.LauncherUtil.verifyJdkVersion(LauncherUtil.java:170)
    at oracle.ide.osgi.boot.LauncherUtil.checkLaunchPrerequisites(LauncherUtil.java:126)
    at oracle.ide.osgi.boot.LauncherUtil.initialize(LauncherUtil.java:98)
    at oracle.ide.osgi.boot.OracleIdeLauncher.main(OracleIdeLauncher.java:80)
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by uninstalling the OpenJDK 18-* version of JDK and installing the Oracle JDK version 11.